# Linea Horizontal en una tabla en php

Tags: php, sql-server

Quiero poner una linea horizontal para separar datos al momento de visualizarse en un DGV en php, utilizo un 'echo' junto con un '' para crear la tabla, pero quiero separarlo por lineas los registros dentro del echo al momento de crear la tabla, anexo el codigo hasta el momento

```
$query = $db->prepare($sql); 
$query->execute(); 

echo  '<thead>
        <tr>    
          <th nowrap>Pregunta</th>
          <th nowrap>Respuesta</th>
          <th nowrap>Imagen</th>
          <th nowrap>Video</th>
          <th nowrap>Firma</th>
        </tr>
       </thead>

       <tbody>';
       foreach ($query as $valor) {
             echo  '<br />
            <tr>
              <td nowrap  style="width: 350px; text-align:center;">'. $valor[0] . '</td>
              <td nowrap  style="width: 120px; text-align:center;">'  . $valor[1] . '</td>
              <td nowrap  style="width: 200px; text-align:center;"><a target="_blank"  href="../img_uploaded/'.$valor[2].'" rel="lightbox" >' . $valor[2] . '</a></td>                       
              <td nowrap  style="width: 200px; text-align:center;"><a target="_blank"  href="../img_uploaded/'.$valor[3].'" rel="lightbox" width="150" height="150" >' . $valor[3] . '</a></td>
              <td nowrap  style="width: 200px; text-align:center;"><a target="_blank"  href="../img_uploaded/'.$valor[4].'" rel="lightbox" >' . $valor[4] . '</a></td>  <br>        
            </tr> <br />';    
       }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con `<hr />` se puede hacer una linea horizontal, ojala te sirva!
El ejemplo completo sería:

```
$query = $db->prepare($sql); 
$query->execute(); 

echo '
  <thead>
    <tr>    
      <th nowrap>Pregunta</th>
      <th nowrap>Respuesta</th>
      <th nowrap>Imagen</th>
      <th nowrap>Video</th>
      <th nowrap>Firma</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>';
   foreach ($query as $valor) {
     echo  '
       <br />
       <tr>
         <td nowrap  style="width: 350px; text-align:center;">'. $valor[0] . '</td>
         <td nowrap  style="width: 120px; text-align:center;">'  . $valor[1] . '</td>
         <td nowrap  style="width: 200px; text-align:center;"><a target="_blank"  href="../img_uploaded/'.$valor[2].'" rel="lightbox" >' . $valor[2] . '</a></td>                       
         <td nowrap  style="width: 200px; text-align:center;"><a target="_blank"  href="../img_uploaded/'.$valor[3].'" rel="lightbox" width="150" height="150" >' . $valor[3] . '</a></td>
         <td nowrap  style="width: 200px; text-align:center;"><a target="_blank"  href="../img_uploaded/'.$valor[4].'" rel="lightbox" >' . $valor[4] . '</a></td>  <br>        
       </tr>
       <br /> 
       <hr />';    
   }
```

Y si lo que quieres es separar cada registro deberías poner a cada  una clase que tenga `border: 1px solid black`

Comment: pero el <hr /> iria dentro del echo? ya use eso y no me muestra nada mas que la pura tabla con los datos

Comment: Después del último <br /> un <hr /> debería funcionar

Comment: Hola @MiGu3X, incluye el ejemplo completo si puedes!

Comment: Esta no debería ser la respuesta aceptada. El código genera HTML inválido, dentro de un `<tbody>`sólo puede haber `<tr>` y acá se están agregando `<br>` y `<hr>`.

Answer (score 1):

También puedes usar un

```
<tr>
    <td height="1" colspan="aqui tu número de columnas" style="border-bottom:1px solid #aquí tu color"></td>
</tr>
```

Es una celda adicional con un borde inferior. Puedes adicionarle el color que desees

**EDITO:** Si deseas que dibuje la línea cada N iteraciones, solo usa:

$contador = 1;

```
foreach ($query as $valor) {
    echo 'aqui los valores';
    if($valordecorte % $contador == 0){
        entonces inserto el separador
}


       }
```

Comment: Esto pedazo de codigo me funciono muy bien, solo qe si lo metro dentro del ciclo separa registro por registro con una linea, pero yo solo quiero que separa por ejemplo en 5 y 5, nose si me explique?

Comment: Añade un contador. Cuando sea múltiplo de 5, que dibuje la línea, de lo contrario no

Comment: Recuerda marcar la respuesta como aceptada si te sirvió y/o actualizar la pregunta si tienes más requerimientos

Comment: ya quedo! Muchas Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Podes hacer algo como lo siguiente:

```
<style>
    .line td {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    }
</style>
<?php

$rows = array(
    array('Pregunta?', 'Respuesta!', 'imagen', 'video', 'firma'),
    array('Pregunta?', 'Respuesta!', 'imagen', 'video', 'firma'),
    array('Pregunta?', 'Respuesta!', 'imagen', 'video', 'firma'),
    array('Pregunta?', 'Respuesta!', 'imagen', 'video', 'firma'),
    array('Pregunta?', 'Respuesta!', 'imagen', 'video', 'firma'),
    array('Pregunta?', 'Respuesta!', 'imagen', 'video', 'firma'),
    array('Pregunta?', 'Respuesta!', 'imagen', 'video', 'firma'),
    array('Pregunta?', 'Respuesta!', 'imagen', 'video', 'firma'),
    array('Pregunta?', 'Respuesta!', 'imagen', 'video', 'firma'),
    array('Pregunta?', 'Respuesta!', 'imagen', 'video', 'firma'),
    array('Pregunta?', 'Respuesta!', 'imagen', 'video', 'firma'),
);

$table  = '';
$counter = 1; // Contador de registros agregados
$module = 5; // Cada cuantos registros vamos a "agregar" una linea horizontal
foreach ($rows as $row) {

    $class = (($counter % $module) === 0) ? 'line' : '';
    $table .=  '
        <tr class="'.$class.'">
          <td nowrap  style="width: 350px; text-align:center;">'. $row[0] . '</td>
          <td nowrap  style="width: 120px; text-align:center;">'  . $row[1] . '</td>
          <td nowrap  style="width: 200px; text-align:center;"><a target="_blank"  href="../img_uploaded/'.$row[2].'" rel="lightbox" >' . $row[2] . '</a></td>                       
          <td nowrap  style="width: 200px; text-align:center;"><a target="_blank"  href="../img_uploaded/'.$row[3].'" rel="lightbox" width="150" height="150" >' . $row[3] . '</a></td>
          <td nowrap  style="width: 200px; text-align:center;"><a target="_blank"  href="../img_uploaded/'.$row[4].'" rel="lightbox" >' . $row[4] . '</a></td>  <br>        
        </tr>';
    $counter++;
}
?>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>    
            <th nowrap>Pregunta</th>
            <th nowrap>Respuesta</th>
            <th nowrap>Imagen</th>
            <th nowrap>Video</th>
            <th nowrap>Firma</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody><?php echo $table; ?></tbody>
</table>
```

Aquí dejo el link a una demo: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/06ft-ijse

Answer (score 0):

Lo mas práctico es ponerle el borde en el  `tr` y ponerle el border-collapse en el `table`, para que abarque todos los `td`, asi:

```
<table style="border-collapse: collapse">
.
.
.
<tr style="border-bottom:1px solid grey">
    <td>. . . . </td>
</tr>
```